# How do JavaScript runtimes implement binding functions to objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, programming-languages, interpreter, instance-methods

I'm implementing a JavaScript interpreter, and I can't figure out the details of binding functions to objects in JavaScript.

A rudimentary example:

```js
const o = {
  x: 1,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
};
o.getX(); // returns 1
```

The tricky part is what happens when you assign `getX` to a variable:

```js
let gX = o.getX;
gX(); // returns undefined
```

My question is: how does the runtime know that `o.getX()` gets bound to `o`, but `gX()` should be unbound? I would assume `gX` and `o.getX` are pointing to the exact same function!

I first thought that maybe the presence of the `.` is what makes the difference. So, in the grammar, there's a production like `<method-call> ::= <expr> '.' ID '(' <expr>* ')'`, and this expression is treated differently (the result of evaluating the first `<expr>` is bound to the function found under `ID`) than a "regular" call (without a `.`).

But the following expression seems to disprove this theory, because `(o.getX)()` also returns `1`. However, in some magical way, `(gX = o.getX)()` returns `undefined`, even though it's clear to me the assignment expression returns its right-hand size, so `o.getX` in this case!

Is there a simple explanation of how these semantics are implemented? I can't figure out a way that my runtime is supposed to differentiate that `o.getX` is bound to `o`, but `gX`, even though it's pointing at `o.getX`, is not bound.

Comment: When talking about functions defined with `function` keyword, a simple rule is, that `this` is _always_ bound when the function is _called_, without exceptions (sometimes it's a bit hidden where exactly a function is actually called). See [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-objects) for more details.

Comment: *"My question is: how does the runtime know that `o.getX()` gets bound to `o`, but `gX()` should be unbound? ... I first thought that maybe the presence of the `.` is what makes the difference."* Not the `.` per se (it works with bracket notation as well), but yes, the fact that the function call is happening on the immediate result of a property access operation is what tells the JavaScript engine what value to use as `this` when calling the function. Some of the answers to the linked questions go into the technical detail, but: If we start with ...

Comment: ... [property accessors](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation), you can see that the result (via [EvaluatePropertyAccessWithIdentifierKey](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-evaluate-property-access-with-identifier-key)) of *MemberExpression `.` IdentifierName* (for example) is a [Reference Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-reference-record-specification-type) that ...

Comment: ... includes the object resulting from *MemberExpression* as its [[Base]] value. That Reference Record is used when doing the [function call](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and eventually in [EvaluateCall](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-evaluatecall), where it gets the *thisValue* to use from the Reference Record's [[Base]]. ...

Comment: ... When just doing `gX()`, there is no property expression, and the *ref* used with EvaluateCall isn't a Reference Record, so the *thisValue* used is `undefined`. (The `[[Call]]` internal method of the function may convert `undefined` to `globalThis` if it's a loose-mode function; and of course, arrow functions ignore the `this` they're called with&nbsp;&mdash; but those are different topics.)